# Can not boot from Usb - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04

I first started using Ubuntu on my laptop and decided also to install it onto my desktop. Where all the annoyance began. I did download the source from Ubuntu webpage, transferred the file via Rufus to the same Usb Drive which I used back when I properly installed Ubuntu on my laptop.

But in desktop it does not boot. I do get into the Boot Menu, Select USB-HDD to install Ubuntu, but in every try it starts Windows all over again. So I did some research, changed the Primary Boot to USB from BIOS. Tried again and it is still opening Windows and furthermore USD-HDD does not appear on the top on Boot Menu. No other Usb is connected while attempting installation, I do everything by the book but it does not work.

Hoping to find some answers. I was really getting used to Ubuntu on my laptop :(

**Thanks**

Comment: I already wrote a answer to this problem for another one. [Try that solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266374/1115698)

Comment: Now when I tried Etcher, it does not even flash the file. Gives a "Failed Target" error at the end and the usb becomes unusable . So I thought the Usb might be corrupted and I bought a brand new one hoping it won't give the same error. But it did. I changed the ports plugging the usb and still the same "Checksum drive does not match range" error. I am literally speechless, as such an easy task has given me so much headache.

Comment: As a starter: Does the current live system in the USB drive boot your laptop? If not, check the md5sum. Try with Rufus in 'dd-mode' which means the reliable cloning method, or create the boot drive in your laptop with Ubuntu - use the Startup Disk Creator. What graphics chip is there (brand name and model)? Maybe you need the boot option `nomodeset` in the desktop computer.

Answer (score -1):

How did you download the image file. if you used something like idman may be you have corrupt iso file. so download again in your browser and try again. If your usb is unusable leave me message. i'll help you