# How to dual boot Ubuntu+Windows 10 in HP ProBook?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, hp

I am using HP ProBook x360.I have Windows 10 installed and I am trying to dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.I have created a bootable pendrive and I have checked that legacy support in enabled in BIOS.

On restarting, when I go to the boot menu and click on the USB option I get more options(all the files present inside the USB). In the YouTube videos that I have watched just clicking on the USB option started the installation process.

To be more specific I am getting this(image given below) and I don't know what I am supposed to select.Should I click on install? I didn't try it because I was afraid something might go wrong.

[image: Boot Menu Image]

Comment: may I know how did you make your flashdrive bootable, because this seems to be the content of USB, if it was bootable you show see Linux installer

Comment: I used rufus to write the Ubuntu iso file to my pendrive.

Comment: Try to make another bootable flashdrive and see if you get same window pop-up

Comment: I did it with Etcher  as mentioned by @Rasindu Nimsara and it worked.don't know what was wrong with Rufus though.

Comment: Good to hear it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I faced same matter when i was a beginner. This is something wrong when you creating the boot drive. What is shown in your image is the content of the usb. Literary Rufus is not a very good tool for creating bootable drives for linux. So try another software like balena Etcher. You can download windows version the website.  [You Can Go To Website Using This Link](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)

Comment: Thank You! This worked.