# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on newly built PC

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, msi

I just built a new PC, and would really like to run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, as I've never used Linux before and want to use it. For three days now, I have not been able to install it onto my hard drive. Here are the components of the computer.

Motherboard: MSI b550-a pro
CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon RX 580
Hard drive: Adapta sxg6000 M.2 nvme

The steps I have used to install Ubuntu are 1) Burn ubuntu ISO (from ubuntu website)
onto a flash drive, boot to the flash drive, and attempt the install.

I have tried multiple different USBs, I have tried Ubuntu, Mint, and Elementary OS, I
tried a sata connected SSD and a nvme M.2 hard drive, but they all have the same result.

The install starts off well, and then I get the error 'Executing 'grub install /dev/nvme0n1' failed. This is a fatal error.', When I tried to SSD the error was 'Executing 'grub install /dev/sda' failed. This is a fatal error.

I feel like I've tried just about everything. I really don't know what to do. This is my last
resort. My last guess is that perhaps the motherboard is incompatible with Linux. Do you guys have any suggestions?

[Also worth noting -- I'm not super techy, if you need a log of info, please let me know how to obtain the data]

Thank you to whoever tries to help me. Seriously.

Edit 1:
I forgot to mention, when I boot to the grub menu where I can select "Ubuntu", "Ubuntu (graphics safe)" etc., I edit using "e" and add nomodeset and acpi=off. Originally I couldn't even boot to the flash drive, but after that fix, I was able to get to the "Try/Install Ubuntu" phase, but my progress pretty much ended there.

Comment: Well motherboard can't be incompatible with Linux. and the errors you mentioned seems switched, it doesn't matter though. The problem seems that the grub is unable to install in your drive. However you booted to grub menu, so probably it was installed but not correctly. If your system is new then it should support UEFI. Is there any other operating installed on your system?

Comment: I have two adapta m.2 drives, I installed Windows 10 on the first one, then removed it from the motherboard and inserted the second m.2 drive. Also, what do you mean I booted to the grub menu?

Comment: Didn't you say in your edit 1 : " I forgot to mention, when I boot to the grub menu ". I am not 100% sure but the removal of your 1st drive could be somehow related to the grub related issue. You could read : https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/bootup.html. It could be issue but again not 100% sure. @oldfred might be able to help

Comment: I apologize, I believe I said that wrong. I meant that when I insert my bootable flash drive, and boot to it, I am always welcomed to a GNU Grub Screen where I can choose either Ubuntu, Ubuntu (safe graphics), etc. , I edit the command there, then boot into Ubuntu from the flash drive. The screen I' talking about is at the 1:34 mark in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ffzC4S0A4&t=93s Is this the Grub Menu you are talking about?

Comment: My apologies I misinterpreted that statement. May I know how to made a bootable flashdrive. Sometimes there is issue in bootable USB itself. I recommend re-trying the process again. You can read this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266359/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntuwindows-10-in-hp-probook#comment2143855_1266359

Comment: Hey @WhiteMars, thank you for your feedback! I made multiple bootable flash drives, using Rufus 3.11, I used the formats MBR and GPT, I also tried balenaEtcher. I will read the links you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 installs in UEFI mode.  You can't just disconnect the Windows drive to install Ubuntu like you could with BIOS systems, because you're disconnecting the drive with your EFI partition. You did right by installing windows first, but don't disconnect it.  Just **pay close attention** when you install Ubuntu that you don't overwrite Windows.  There should even be a "Install Alongside Windows" option that will set up GRUB so you can successfully dual boot.  Please review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Even with two separate hard drives one storing Windows and one storing Linux? If this is the solution, I'm 1) going to be relieved and 2) upset how simple that is.

Comment: I put in the Windows 10 M.2 in the computer (now the computer has both M.2 hard drives in it), and I booted to the USB, chose the "Install alongisde windows" option, and hit the same "Executing grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 failed.